# I can't add annotations in the mapview by using latitude and longitude

Tags: annotations, android-mapview

I have read the latitudes and longitudes from an xml file, and I want to add some annotations with them. But except the user location, none of them was added.The count of mapview.annotations is always empty.Here is my code:

```
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if (newLocation != nil) {
        self.myLocation = newLocation;
    }


    mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(self.myLocation.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.005f, 0.005f));
    mapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
    //mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    mapView.centerCoordinate = self.myLocation.coordinate;


    MKPointAnnotation *userLocation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    userLocation.coordinate = myLocation.coordinate;
    userLocation.title = @"my position";
    userLocation.subtitle = @"my position now";
    [mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];

    [mapView addAnnotation:userLocation];
    [userLocation release];

    if ([self.positionArray count] < 5) {
        NSString *dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"position" ofType:@"xml"];
        NSData *positionData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:dataPath];

        NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:positionData];

        parser.delegate = self;

        [parser parse];
    }

    if (self.myLocation != nil) {
        [self.manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }


}
```

And here is the MapInfo class:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface MapInfo : NSObject<MKAnnotation>
{
    NSString *subtitle;
    NSString *title;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location;
- (void)setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate;

@end
```

Then here is the delegate method

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifer";
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapInfo class]]) {
        if (pinView == nil) {
            pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.animatesDrop = NO;
    }else if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]])
    {
        if (pinView == nil) {
            pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.animatesDrop = NO;
    }
    return pinView;
}
```

I really don't know why only the user location can be added,someone help me please!!It has bothered me for several days!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have forgotten to set the mapView's delegate.